# Maven - Spring Refer Bean from Interface

Tags: java, spring, maven-3

I have following scenario and need advice on how to handle.

My project is Maven module with spring.

I have following modules.

1.module A - WAR

2.module B - WAR

3.module C - JAR

Module dependency as follows.

module A and B have module C as dependency.

I have a service which related to module A. The implementation is done in module A. This service needs to be access by module B. Now what i did was to introduce a interface to module C (jar) to access this service. The implementation is left on module A ( which service really belongs). Module B access this service through interface and project compiles. But the problem is spring cannot create bean for this service in module B. This is understandable since bean ( implementation ) never there in module B's dependency list. How can I address this ? I don't want to move whole service to module B since it would be huge code duplicate.

Comment: Looks like you need to tune the @ComponentScan to find the implementations in other packages/libraries.

Comment: why don't you move the bean implementation to module C?

Comment: @Alex I did this ( using xml ). But did not help. How can spring create a bean if there's no implementation class file in that module's dependency.

Comment: It cannot. You need at least one concrete implementation of the bean interface for the creation of a spring bean. You can definitely move the implementation to module C. I can give a sample implementation in the answer. Or  you can state what is the problem you faced and we can dig further.

Comment: @yaswanth The implementation already there in module A. This is actually shared service but the most of this responsibility belongs to module A. Moving this module C means adding unnecessary responsibility to module C.

Comment: Let me get the question clear. What do you mean by a service? Is it a bare spring bean or something else?

Comment: @yaswanth. It just a bean. As a class it can be move to module C. There's no technological issue there. But the problem is this bean does not belong in module C. Adding it there seems not correct.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to access the spring bean if the implementation is in module A which is not related to module B. module B needs some way to get hold of the implementation. Duplicating the implementation seems to be only way I can think of. If you are ok with having the interface in module C, why is module C not the right place to include it's implementation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> " The implementation is left on module A ( which service really
>   belongs)."

It should not as module A and module B are two distinct WARs and that these have no relation between them actually.
If you want each WAR holds the implementation at runtime, you should include the component implementation in each WAR.

The implementation should be in a common jar : the module C or another one.

Now, if you want that the service provided by this implementation be only in the module A. The WAR build by the module A should expose a service (REST for example) to allow the module B to call it.
But I am not sure that you want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> This is actually shared service but the most of this responsibility
>   belongs to module A. Moving this module C means adding unnecessary
>   responsibility to module C

Maybe you could implement the shared functionality in module C and extends the service with the extra responsibilities into module A